# Set authorization in Node request.headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, satellizer

I'm attempting to send a Passport-Local login request to the client side to be analyzed by Satellizer, and I would like the request from the server side to send an authorization token. Unfortunately, there is no key `authorization` in `request.headers`:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' }
```

The login function redirects here, and this is where `ensureAuthenticated()` is called.

```
app.get('/main', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('main.ejs', { token: createSendToken(req.user, config.secret), id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, authorization: req.user.authorization });
});
```

`ensureAuthenticated()` then analyzes the login request and makes sure the tokens match:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
     return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header' });
  }
  var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

  var payload = null;
  try {
    payload = jwt.decode(token, config.token_secret);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: err.message });
  }

  if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired' });
  }
  req.user = payload.sub;
  next();
}
```

It then redirects and shows the message

```
{ message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header' }
```

**How would I set an authorization key to request.headers?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the `authorization` key in the header?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `request.headers.authorization = value`

Comment: Okay, I could have guessed that. In that case, where in my code would it be best to set that? During passport authentication? A whole new function?

Comment: I haven't seen your code, so hard to guess. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set a new header field in the request just access it directly, as the headers object looks like a normal hash table.

```
request.headers.authorization = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was simple, albeit a little work: I need to create my own custom passport login function to send a token before the `ensureAuthenticated()` function was called.

Old login function:

```
app.post('/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local-login',
    {   successRedirect: '/main',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        message: null,
        failureFlash: true
    }));
```

New custom login function:

```
app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.login(user, function(err){
            var token = createSendToken(user, config.secret);
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (token == (null || undefined)) { return next(err); }
            res.status(200).send({ token: token });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Once it gets redirected to `/main` then the `ensureAuthenticated()` function is called and everything works as it should.

Comment: You should be able to do this like this: `app.post('/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', { failureRedirect: '/login' }, function (res, req) { // your success function });`